# tkinter py script gives different output when called from another script

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I wrote a script in a .py file that I would like to call from another main file of my program. But when I do that, it does not initialize and give the same output as when runned directly.

here's the code of the main file where I import the subTest file as a module and call it when the user clicks on a button:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import subTest
from subTest import SubTest

class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Test")
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry("600x300+30+30")
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Test")
        label.pack(pady=20,padx=10)
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text='gotosubtest', command =   self.callsubtest)
        self.button.pack()

    def callsubtest(self):    
        app = SubTest(None)
        app.mainloop()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(None)
    window.mainloop()
```

and here's the code of the subTest file containing an Entry text box which should be initialized at 320. This is a simplified example of the problem. when subTest is executed directly, this Entry default value is shown in the text box. But when subTest is called from the main, the value is not shown. 
Any idea what's wrong with my code? thanks in advance to all useful tips for a python beginner ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Entry

class SubTest(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "SubTest")
        self.parent = parent
        self.initializesubtest()

    def initializesubtest(self):
        self.geometry("510x480")

        self.minx = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.minx.set(320)
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.minx,width=5).grid(row=21,column=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Min X").grid(row=22,column=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SubTest(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have a single instance of `Tk` in a program. When you use that other module you are creating a second root window. For you to be able to use that second module in the first, it cannot create its own root window.

Comment: Thanks! it seems by replacing in the subTest script tk.Tk by Toplevel, it works.